# Convert date format from string

Tags: java, android

I have a string where contain date and time with format like this

"2020-09-20-08-40"

i try to convert that string to date with format "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm" and print that in a textview. I saw other people try convert with this way

```
        String dateString = "2020-09-20-08-40"
        SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
        SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
        Date date = format1.parse(dateString);
        String dateFinal = format2.format(date);
        t_date.setText(dateFinal);
```

when i try this way, i got error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

How to solve this?

Comment: Do you notice the `-` between your day and your hour? How are you addressing this issue? What research have you done to try to solve this problem by yourself? Since Java8 there are new classes to deal with Date handling - why are you not using?

Comment: I only know to handle that if there only date, not both. So i ask here if i can handle if there both avalaible

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime.parse( 
    "2020-09-20-08-40" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd-HH-mm" ) 
)
```

See [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/RdqQDY).

> 2020-09-20T08:40

## Details

Avoid using terrible legacy date-time classes. Use only *java.time* classes.

Define a formatting pattern to match your input.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd-HH-mm" ) ;
```

Parse your input text.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

Tip: Educate the publisher of your data about the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard for exchanging date-time values as text. No need to be inventing such formats as seen in your Question. The *java.time* classes use the standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings, so no need to specify a formatting pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Nima Khalili and @Andre Artus answer, i can solve this. My code will look this

```
        String dateString = "2020-09-20-08-40" 
        SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm");
        format1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT + 7"));
        SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
        Date date;
        try {
            date = format1.parse(dateString);
            String dateFinal = format2.format(date);
            t_date.setText(dateFinal);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Your code ignores the crucial issue of time zone. A `java.util.Date` represents a moment as seen in UTC (offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds). But your input string has no indicator of time zone or offset. Square peg, round hole.

Comment: @BasilBourque i just realize that issue, thank for correcting me. I have updated my code

Answer (score -1):

If you have a date+time like "2020-09-20-08-40" then your format should reflect that, e.g.

"yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm"

Comment: What if i delete all "-", will it be yyyy MM dd HH mm?